# JVM first 4 booleans optimized, not 5th

Tags: java, memory, jvm, micro-optimization

I'm currently profiling some Java application using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer plugin (using a standard jconsole *hprof* dump), and I noticed some strange results on computed object size:

```
private static class B1 extends B {
} // 16 bytes

private static class B2 extends B {
    boolean d1;
    boolean d2;
    boolean d3;
    boolean d4;
} // also 16 bytes!

private static class B3 extends B {
    boolean d1;
    boolean d2;
    boolean d3;
    boolean d4;
    boolean d5;
} // 24 bytes
```

Apparently the first 4 booleans are somehow stuffed away in the object header, **how is this?**

*Note: Tested with Oracle JDK1.7 and JDK1.8, 64 bits, running on Linux x64.*

Comment: profiling `boolean` is a very bad idea since they are the only primitive with non fixed byte size.

Comment: By default `-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=8` this simplified object allocation, however it can have significant padding for small objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within 64-bit HotSpot JVM with CompressedOops

- Object header consists of 8 byte `markWord` + 4 byte `instanceKlass` reference
- `boolean` field occupy 1 byte
- Objects are 8-byte aligned

That is

- an empty object occupies `align8(8 + 4) = 16 bytes`
- an object with 4 boolean fields occupy `align8(8 + 4 + 4*1) = 16 bytes`
- an object with 5 boolean fields occupy `align8(8 + 4 + 5*1) = align8(17) = 24 bytes`

Answer (score 5):

There is no optimization going on; the object header is commonly 8 or 12 bytes large, depending on VM and mode (Compressed OOPS on/off). Also commonly the memory granularity is 8 bytes (Object sizes in memory must *always* be a multiple of the granularity).

Your results clearly indicate that your VM uses a 12 byte header; so there is room for 4 bytes due to granularity without growing the obbject memory footprint. The booleans are commonly represented as bytes; so adding a 5th in your case requires 17 bytes (12 header + 5 bytes) rounded to next granularity 8 boundary gives 24 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing what you are.   Using 1.8, from Netbeans:

```
public static class C1 {
    boolean a,b,c,d;
}
public static class C2 {
    boolean a,b,c,d,e;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
           Constructor<Unsafe> unsafeConstructor = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
           unsafeConstructor.setAccessible(true);
           Unsafe unsafe = unsafeConstructor.newInstance();
           String[] fieldNames = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};
           for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
           System.out.println(fieldName+": "+unsafe.objectFieldOffset(C1.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName)));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

yields the result

```
a: 12
b: 13
c: 14
d: 15
```

...which indicates that each boolean value occupies a separate byte offset in the object.  The header is 12 bytes.